# Where is the memory for ubuntu if whole memory is used for windows

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning

On a computer, during the installation of ubuntu, there are two devices listed: `/dev/sda` for whole hard disk and `/dev/sda1` (80GB) for windows. So the whole memory is used for windows. However, when I checked which OS installed to the device from boot menu I saw that they were both windows and ubuntu. If the whole memory is used for windows how there could be ubuntu as well?

Comment: upload gparted screenshot,i will tell you where is the memory for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install using Wubi? If so, your Ubuntu files will all be located within a file called `root.disk`. Otherwise, there should be a separate partition with the OS installed on it. Open up Disks in Ubuntu and see if it shows up there.